# Turn on() event back after apply off

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I turn an `on('click')` event back on after I apply event `off()`?

```
$('#btn-aluno').on('click', function() {
    $('.new-step-email-aluno').toggle();
    $('#btn-familiar').off();
});
$('#btn-familiar').on('click', function() {
    $('.new-step-email-familiar').toggle();
    $('#btn-aluno').off();
});
```

`new-step-email-familiar` and `new-step-email-aluno` = `<input>`

`btn-aluno` and `btn-familiar` = `<span>` (used as a button)

[image]

Comment: why'd you turn it off in the first place? don't turn it off

Comment: If you need to turn on after it turns off, the most probably thing that you need is no turn off. Simple.

Comment: This is so confusing, what are you trying to do on the page?

Comment: [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of turning off the event listener, you could do the same thing by using `event delegation`,

```
$(document).on('click',"#btn-aluno.active", function() {
    $('.new-step-email-aluno').toggle();
    $('#btn-familiar').removeClass("active");
});

$(document).on('click',"#btn-familiar.active", function() {
    $('.new-step-email-familiar').toggle();
    $('#btn-aluno').removeClass("active");
});
```

And whenever you want to activate the event listeners, just add the class `active` to the relevant elements. Also in the place of `document` try to use any closest static parent of the element on which the event gonna be bound.

---

As per your requirement, you have edit your logic like below,

```
$(document).on('click',"#btn-aluno.active", function() {
    $('.new-step-email-aluno').toggle();
    $('#btn-familiar').toggleClass("active");
});

$(document).on('click',"#btn-familiar.active", function() {
    $('.new-step-email-familiar').toggle();
    $('#btn-aluno').toggleClass("active");
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/dzwfxg2j/3/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, when I click on #btn-aluno the button #btn-familiar  stay disabled  it's OK, but when I click again on #btn-aluno the button #btn-familiar still stay disabled ... oO

Comment: @erickcouto What is your requirement actually?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dzwfxg2j/    When I click on #btn-aluno the input .new-step-email-aluno hide() and the button #btn-familiar disable OK and when I click again on #btn-aluno the input .new-step-email-aluno show() and #btn-familiar enable ...

Comment: Pefect Thank you so much =D

Comment: @erickcouto Glad to help! :)